# How can I save in Dalekjs terminal

Tags: save, phantomjs, interaction

How can I save the content of the 'test' object after its opened?
for example:

```
module.exports = {
  'Page title is correct': function (test) {
   test
       .open('http://google.com')
       // save content of test the HTML DOM
       .assert.title().is('Google', 'It has title')
       .done();
   }
};
```

or maybe to interact directly with phantomJS
It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is not the main purpose of DalekJS to do things like this, it is technically possible to do it like so:

```
module.exports = {
  'Can store html': function (test) {
    test.open('http://google.com')
        .execute(function () {
          this.data('htmlData', window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML);
        })
        .log.message(function () {
           var data = test.data('htmlData');
           var fs = require('fs');
           fs.writeFileSync('nameOfTheFile.html', data);
           return data;
         })
        .assert.title().is('Google', 'It has title')
        .done();
  }
};
```

We execute some in browser JavaScript using the `execute` method & pipe it over to node using the `data('key', 'value')` storage method.

We access this data later in our `log.message` method which runs in the node context. This enables us to load the `FileSystem` module & finally to store the captured html into a file.